# Countable set X

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone help me with proving that if any set $A$ is at most countable the there exists 1-1 function $f:A \to \mathbb N.$

I tried to prove that by contrapositive but I could not.
Also I assume for sake a contradiction that there is no 1-1 function but I did not see any contradiction .

Comment: What's your definition of at most countable?

Comment: Taking A={a1,a2,…}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is at most countable.

Then you can enumerate $A$: 
$$
A = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}. \tag{*}
$$
Define $f: A \to \mathbb N$ by
$$
f(a) = \text{The index of $a$ in the enumeration (*)},
$$
for any $a\in A.$ (e.g. if $a=a_{17}$, then $f(a) = 17.$)

Then $f$ is injective.

Comment: OHHHHH , OK I GOT IT ,thank you so much.